# Im currently writing a gravity simulation and I am getting a type Error in my code

Tags: python, numpy

The Problem occurs in line 29:
It is a Type Error

I can't figure out where I went wrong with my parameters. It should assign every `a[i][k]` with a value but it just ends up with the following error message:

```
a[i][k].append(g * m[i] * dr[k]/d3) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here the full code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import absolute
from numpy import power

r = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]
v = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
a = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
m = [1,1,1]
O = -1
N = 3

def beschleunigung(O, N, m, r, a):
    i = 0
    k = 0
    dr = [0,0,0]
    d3 = 0
    g = 1

    for k in range(1,3):
        a[i][k] = 0
    for i in range(1,N):
        if i != O:
            for k in range(1,3):
                a = (r[i][k])
                b = (r[0][k])
                dr[k] = a - b
                d3 = np.power(np.absolute(dr),3)
            for k in range(1,3):
                a[i][k].append(g * m[i] * dr[k]/d3)


beschleunigung(O,N,m,r,a)
print(a[1])
```

Comment: On this line `a = (r[i][k])` you are changing the type of `a` to be an `int`, hiding your original list of lists.

Comment: That's because you used `a = (r[i][k])`, `a` became an integer

Answer (score 1):

When your code executes the line `a = (r[i][k])`, `a` becomes an integer, rather than a list of lists as it was in the input to this function. This causes your `append` to fail as you cannot `append` to an integer.

I expect that you intended to create another variable to use in your subtraction with `b` - make sure to use a name that is not already defined in your scope.